# How to open master node of aws ec2 in ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, kubernetes

I have created kubernetes cluster using kops and kubectl in main EC2 instance and master-child node created automatically.

```
kops create cluster \
--state=${KOPS_STATE_STORE} \
--node-count=2 \
--master-size=t2.medium \
--node-size=t2.medium \
--zones=ap-south-1a,ap-south-1b \
--name=${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME} \
--dns private \
--master-count 1
```

I am able to connect kops ec2 instance(main) from git bash,or directly. But I am not able to open master instance either way.

```
 ssh -i key1.pem ec2-user@kops-ip  #working for kops
```

While connecting to master node its giving:

```
There was a problem setting up the instance connection
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.
```

My question is:

**1.How to open master ec2 instance?**

**2.Do I need to install kubernetes dashboard in master or in kops instance(currently having)?**

AWS Instances:

```
kops(ec2-user)
master-ap-south-1a.masters.a.com
nodes.a.com 
nodes.a.com
```

Comment: What is the version of kops and is there any particular tutorial you have been using (would like to reproduce)? When did you lost an access to Master?  Was it after creating pod network on master?

Comment: Version 1.15.0 (git-9992b4055) 
I created master and 2 children from kops which is in diff ec2... 
when I open kops-ec2 instance its opening using pem file 
but the master instance not opening

Comment: Please try the following (with your admin/root user)

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/kube_aws_rsa admin@<masterip>`

and `kube_aws_rsa` is the default key generated, otherwise controlled with AWS_SSH_KEY environment variable. For AWS, it is specified in the file cluster/aws/config-default.sh.

More details about the cluster can be found using `kubectl.sh config view`.